# Adobe Illustrator doesn't change units from points (pt) to pixels (px)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, units

Text items in my project are measured with pixels as I need it to be, but shapes - only in points, even though there are "Pixels" selected in Preferences->Units.

In other project files everything's okay.

Comment: You realize for Adobe apps... 1pt = 1px.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

check your document setup, and make sure that is set to pixels as well...

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Solution: Turn on the ruler via the view menu. Select it.
Now right click the ruler on canvas and choose pixels.

Answer (score 0):

Just to iterate on this - if you are seeing it in pixels (for example) and it's says in document properties it's set up as mm, just changed it to and from pixels back to mm and it'll sort itself out. This also works in Illi CS4/5/6 - where I'd get px based eps/pdf/ai assets from clients/contractors etc.